# FPDF : Table Cell Line Break after 10 cells

Tags: fpdf

hey guys its me again

I am trying to copy this output 
[image]

but my output in fpdf is like this

[image]

and this is my code:

```
    $pdf = new PDF();
    $pdf->AliasNbPages();
    $pdf->AddPage('L');
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',11);
    $pdf->Cell(112);
    $pdf->Cell(45,10,'Teacher'."'s ".'Table',1,'','C');
    $pdf->Ln(20);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $fname = $row['stud_fname'];
        $lname = $row['stud_lname'];

        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',11);
        $pdf->Cell(35,10,$lname.", ".$fname,1,'','C');
    }
    $pdf->Output();
```

the out put should be five cells in the left then (space) and another five cells in the right

Answer (score 0):

make sure you adjust the width of the cell so that could put 11 cell in one line, or if still not have enough space, try to change the font type and size

you should try something like this

```
 $max=50;
 $num=1;
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $fname = $row['stud_fname'];
   $lname = $row['stud_lname'];
   $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',11);
   if ($num mod 5==0 && $num mod 2 == 1){
     $pdf->Cell(5,10,$lname.", ".$fname,1,'','C');
     $pdf->Cell(5,10,'',1,'','C');
   }else if ($num mod 5==0 && $num mod 2 == 0){
     $pdf->Cell(5,10,$lname.", ".$fname,1,1,'C');
   }else{
     $pdf->Cell(5,10,$lname.", ".$fname,1,'','C');
   }
   $num++;
 }
```

by that code, we have to set maximum of the cell that we want to create

first looping we need to create the cell with have a data from database, the second looping we need to create the cell without data

```
 if ($num <= $max){
  for ($i=$num;$i<=$max;$i++){
    if ($num mod 5==0 && $num mod 2 == 1){
     $pdf->Cell(5,10,'',1,'','C');
     $pdf->Cell(5,10,'',1,'','C');
   }else if ($num mod 5==0 && $num mod 2 == 0){
     $pdf->Cell(5,10,'',1,1,'C');
   }else{
     $pdf->Cell(5,10,'',1,'','C');
   }
  }
 }
```

the code should be work, if you still didn't see the five cells in the right the you should change the cell width, font size or type to fit the view with the paper size

You can make some modification to add the number inside the cell

The things that you should pay attention is that the `Cell` function  will be write an overlap text and will not wrap the text except you made changes the core function or you can using `MultiCell` function